# Pull changes for several git-repositories

Tags: git, bash, git-pull

In my folder `~/git` I have more than 20 folders containing git-repositories.
I could pull the changes for each repository by running

```
cd folder1
git pull
cd ..
cd folder2
git pull
cd ..
# etc
```

In bash I could also solve it with a loop:

```
for f in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d);
do
  cd ${f};
  git pull;
  cd..;
done
```

I'm wondering, if there is a more elegant way, e.g. using `xargs` or the `-exec` of `find`.

Comment: What's wrong with the for loop? I'd do it that way, if I needed to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no dir starts with a dot.

```
for f in */; do (cd "$f"; git pull); done
```

Or put a function in your ~/.bashrc and use a simple `git_pull`:

```
git_pull()
{
  oldwd="$PWD"
  cd ~/git
  for f in */; do (cd "$f"; git pull); done
  cd "$oldwd"
}
```